# Laravel search by name about the depth of the relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a simple model called Users, which has the following schema:

```php
| id | name    | father_id |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | John    | NULL      |
| 2  | Robert  | 1         |
| 3  | Jacob   | 2         |
| 4  | William | 3         |
| 5  | David   | 3         |
| 6  | John    | 4         |
| 7  | William | 5         |
| 8  | John    | 7         |
| 9  | Thomas  | 8         |
```

**I want to search with the full name and show approximate results ..**

like Search: William David Jacob Robert John

From left to right

Another example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm5Gd.png)

like Search: Ahmad Suleiman Mohammed Suleiman

Ahmad **His father** Suleiman and , Suleiman **His father** Mohammed and ,Mohammed **His father** Suleiman

UsersController

```php
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->get('q');
        $users = [];

        if ($q) {
            $users = User::with('father')->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$q.'%');
            })
                ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                ->paginate(24);
        }

        return view('users.search', compact('users'));
    }
```

User Model

```php
    public function father()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I want to search by name and show the closest possible relationship through 4 names or 5 names
**I want to search with the full name and show approximate results ..**

Comment: Do you want to get all the fathers details or you want to include children details as well.

Comment: thanks , yes all the fathers details ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Recursive Relationship Method

In the User model, consider adding a recursive relationship to fetch an ancestor chain. This will help in retrieving the hierarchy.

###### User Model (User.php):

```php
public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'father_id');
}

// Recursive relationship to fetch ancestors
public function ancestors()
{
    return $this->father()->with('ancestors');
}
```

###### User Controller (UsersController.php):

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->get('q');
    $users = [];

    if ($q) {
        $names = explode(' ', $q); // Split the query into names

        // Initialize the query
        $query = User::with('ancestors');

        // Loop through each name and refine the query
        foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
            $query->whereHas('ancestors', function ($query) use ($name, $index) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', "%$name%")->whereRaw("depth = $index");
            });
        }

        $users = $query->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(24);
    }

    return view('users.search', compact('users'));
}
```

This approach assumes a `depth` attribute or similar logic to determine the level of the ancestor in the hierarchy, which you might need to implement.